# MySQL Multiple Insert Query Where Not Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

UPDATE & Answer thanks and credit to @ypercube

THe Answer is below and I have taken the liberty of posting it as it appears in my PHP has a helper, I am using PDO

```
    INSERT INTO `users_relationship` (`profile_1_id`, `profile_2_id` ,`request_date`,`auth_token`,`status`, `updated`, `deleted`)
    VALUES
        (:uid, :fid, '$now', '$fToken', 0, '$now',0),
        (:fid, :uid, '$now', '$fToken', 0, '$now',0)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE request_date = VALUES(request_date), auth_token = VALUES(auth_token), updated = VALUES(updated), deleted = VALUES (deleted);
```

---

I have a MySQL query which is puzzling me, the requirement is that I need to create to rows in a table at one time however there maybe a possibility that these rows already exist and so I will need to update some of the columns in this row rather than insert duplicates.

Example

Justin (2) is related to Ben (5), the relationship is then terminated by updating the rows in the database where profile_1_id is 2 or 5 and inserting a flag into the deleted column. Ben then try's to rekindle the relationship and therefore we need to update the rows again and remove the deleted flag and update request_date, auth_token & updated with new values.

I have written the following but it is not firing the error being:

> Duplicate column name '2012-09-05 10:13:06'

```
INSERT INTO `users_relationship` (`profile_1_id`, `profile_2_id`,`request_date`,`auth_token`,`status`, `updated`, `deleted`)
    SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT 2, 5, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 'SQLTEST', 0, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 0) AS faTmp,
        (SELECT 5, 2, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 'SQLTEST', 0, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 0) AS fTmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT  * FROM `users_relationship`WHERE `profile_1_id`=2 AND `profile_2_id` =5) OR 
        (SELECT  * FROM `users_relationship`WHERE `profile_1_id`=5 AND `profile_2_id` =2) LIMIT 1
```

Am I on the right path or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Justin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way seems to be to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(profile_1_id, profile_2_id)` and then use:

```
INSERT INTO `users_relationship` 
  (`profile_1_id`, `profile_2_id`
  ,`request_date`,`auth_token`,`status`, `updated`, `deleted`)
VALUES
  (2, 5, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 'SQLTEST', 0, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 0),
  (5, 2, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 'SQLTEST', 0, '2012-09-05 10:13:06', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  request_date = VALUES(request_date)          --- what you want to happen
, auth_token = VALUES(auth_token)              --- when rows exist
  --- ;
```

Comment: Is that ordered? ie: is (2,5) the same as (5,2)?

Comment: @podiluska: No, a Unique key on `(profile1, profile2)` will allow both `(2,5)` and `(5,2)`

Comment: for the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE element how would I handle multiples would I comma seperate?

Comment: @ypercube I'm interpreting it that the OP wants to only have one of (2,5) and (5,2). Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Every duplicate row will be dealed individually in that part. If you mean columns, yes, comma separated.

Comment: e.g.ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `request_date` = VALUES('2012-09-05 10:13:06'), `auth_token` = VALUES('SQLTEST'), `updated` = VALUES('2012-09-05 10:13:06'), `deleted` = VALUES (0);

Comment: @justin: Don't put values there. Use the statement in my answer, as it is.

Comment: Either `request_date = VALUES(request_date)` or `request_date = '2012-09-05 10:13:06'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, but the syntax is

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS  
        (SELECT  * FROM `users_relationship`WHERE `profile_1_id`=2 AND `profile_2_id` =5) 
 AND  
 NOT EXISTS  
        (SELECT  * FROM `users_relationship`WHERE `profile_1_id`=5 AND `profile_2_id` =2)
```